# Solution deployed in Central Administration, but Web Part missing

Tags: web-part, central-administration

I have WebApp at URL `http://AUrl/`

I have deployed solution with single file in _layout.
And then removed that solution and installed upgrade with new web part in it.

I can see in Central administration that my solution is deployed to `http://AUrl/`

I can not see that web part on `http://AUrl/site/SomeSiteHere`.

Any ideas?

PS I do not have any actual content under `http://AUrl/` accessible via web browser.

**Edit:**
Above feature was scoped as Web App.
I have tried a bit different approach where feature is scoped as Site. Still no luck!
Central admin see it, `http://AUrl/site/SomeSiteHere` do not.

**Update:**
When I have set site url, for second solution (scoped at site!), VS was able to deploy it successfully.

So the question now is:

**How do You deploy solution to web app, when there is no site collection set for web app url? Like `http://AUrl/` is web app url only, and site collection is set at `http://AUrl/sites/SiteA`.**

Comment: You need to activate the Feature at site collection level from site settings...

Comment: I would if I could find it on the list of features.

Comment: is your feature is hidden? check from both Site collection feature or Manage Site Feature? or run the get-spfeature command to see if it is their http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607945(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: get-spfeature return both features (see edit for second one I have missing), I can even use enable-spfeature -URL `http://AUrl/sites/B`, without any errors. Though files that should load on each page (some JS) are not loading.

Comment: what central admin daying, solution is deployed?

Comment: ? "daying" as not working? Yes, now that I tinker with it, there some links in central admin that do not work. Manage web apps, View all site collections. Its fresh installation of SP, so I have no idea if its new development or faulty installation. (However I was able to create 2 site collections before, so at least this link stopped working recently)

Comment: I think, problem with your Code, if you are facing the issues with Central admin or other sites.

Comment: Right now, my code consist of jQuery js, and single script link, in module. (Or View Part that just consist of script tag) Not much to do wrong here. Project/Solution/Feature settings are defaults too :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) My Web App URL is not used by any site collection!
2) Web Parts that are scopped at site, should use site collections url.

There is great post about enabling feautres that are not visible in web admin section here:
[Deployed solution does not appear in site collection features.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17036/deployed-solution-does-not-appear-in-site-collection-features)

With that I was able to deploy Site scopped solution, and get Feature working.

Answer (score 0):

On `http://AUrl/`, go to Site Settings > Site Collection Features and ensure that your web part is activated

Comment: Its not functional url :| I have 2 different site collections under /sites/A and /sites/B. On `http://AUrl/` I get 200 OK HTTP request printed in web browser.

Comment: Is it visible/activated at the top of those site collections?

Comment: No. Features do not show it. Also Central admin do not show that feature. Solution is ivisble and deployed. Features are not.